# Intersect compare vectors in r

Tags: r, vector, compare, intersect

I have a dataframe with 4 colums here is the structure.

I would like to create a new vector (valuetofind) with the value of 1 if all my rows have the number 1 and -1 if all my rows have the number -1.
Otherwhise just fill with NA.

```
str(results)
'data.frame':   435 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ model.knn: Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ p.arbre  : Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ p.svm    : Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ p.rf     : Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...


model.knn p.arbre p.svm p.rf  Valuetofind
    1        1      1    1         1
   -1       -1      1    1        NA
   -1       -1     -1   -1        -1
```

I have been trying many things but I am blocked

I tried to convert to numeric, the facor in my dataframe. It gave me values of 2 and 1 instread of my -1 and 1.

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character())`

Comment: Expanding on @AntoniosK, try `2*as.numeric(as.character()) - 1` to get values `-1` and `1`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas bad advice. You could do `2*as.numeric() - 1` if you want to make strong assumptions about the data (or if you wanted to convert a factor with two arbitrary levels to -1, 1), but since the levels are already `"-1"` and `"1"`,  `as.numeric(as.character())` will work perfectly, and the `as.character` in your suggestion is a bug and will give a bad result.

Comment: @Gregor Right. And I found another bug, the OP wants `-1` or `1` iff all values are `-1` or ´1`, otherwise `NA`. I will answer.

Comment: Thank you, Converting in not really a problem now. I am looking a way to compare the vectors with an efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `ifelse()` and `rowSums()` for `base` solution.

```
results <- data.frame(model.knn = c(1, -1, -1), p.arbre = c(1, -1, -1), p.svm = c(1, 1, -1), p.rf = c(1, 1, -1))

results["Valuetofind"] <- ifelse(rowSums(results) == ncol(results), 1, 
                                  ifelse(rowSums(results) == -ncol(results), -1, NA))

results
  model.knn p.arbre p.svm p.rf Valuetofind
1         1       1     1    1           1
2        -1      -1     1    1          NA
3        -1      -1    -1   -1          -1
```

You can try `dplyr::case_when()` if there are multiple `ifelse()` nesting.